# sybase stored procedure update fails with one of the where clause as timestamp

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, timestamp, sql-update, sybase

I  am  trying  to  execute  a  stored procedure(**sybase database**)  for  a  update  query  with  timestamp  as  one  of  the  where  clause.  But  it  gives as

**Error:** Attempt to insert NULL value into column 'xyz_date', table 'table_xyz'; column does not allow nulls. Update fails.

```
exec procname_update_query '2013-01-01 00:00:00.0', 100.0, 'C'

create proc procname_update_query
@xyz_date datetime,
@field2 float,
@field3 char
as
update table_xyz set value1 = @field2, value2 = @field3,
where  value3 = @xyz_date
```

But When i simply execute as normal update sql statement without using stored procedure , it excutes successfully.

**Note : I have to use stored procedure for this update**

Would be great to if anybody gives a solution

Comment: Assuming that the column `xyz_date` from the error message is actually `value2` from your example, this error could be because you are not passing the length of the char on the stored procedure. What happens if you define your sp as following?: `create proc procname_update_query @xyz_date datetime, @field2 float, @field3 char(1)`

Comment: Describe `table_xyz` table, please.